# Photoshop CS5 Panels, extra ones are open on startup

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to set up a workspace in PS CS5. I create a new one, and set it up how I like, and as there's no explicit save option, I assume it saves on change/on exit. Which is fine, but on starting Photoshop again, it'll open the ones I saved, and some extra ones.

It's the same sort of behaviour as when you open the Layers panel and it attempts to open the other panels which are usually docked in the same group, like Paths. I want to know how to disable this behaviour; not sure what to search for in the help to look for it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, Photoshop doesn't save your Workspace changes on exit, you have to explicitly tell it to save them.

How do you do this?

First set everything as you want it. Then select `Workspace` > `New Workspace`. This will then save your current layout under the Workspace name you provide.

If you want to update an existing Workspace, then do the same, but enter the name of the Workspace you want to update. Then select "Yes" to overwrite the existing settings. A bit annoying, but there you go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this answer doesn't seem to be fully correct: testing with a default workspace (design) and closing the swatches panel, I exited PS and opened again (without declaring a new workspace), and the panel was not there in the design workspace, suggesting it saved my change without me having to do a new workspace. That said, I did set up how I wanted and made my custom workspace which seems to work now, though similarly if I change and close, it remembers the changes I made.

Comment: You're right, it does remember how it is set when you exit Photoshop, but it also allows you to "reset" it. If this feature is working for you, what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: I tested the above on my laptop, where it works. On my work PC, it doesn't - choosing "reset" will make the panels like the swatches come back up, as though it's not recognising any changes after the initial set. They're the same version of PS, same OS (Win7, clean installs) - could there be a setting anywhere (perhaps Windows-side) which is preventing overwriting of the initial workspace?

Comment: Strange, I'm running on a clean install of Win7 using CS5, too. I don't have any issues with it. Weird :(

Comment: marked this as correct answer, as it seems to be an environmental issue - the steps listed in this answer will solve the issue in a working environment. Thanks for the help Johnny.

Comment: Glad you found something that worked for you.